# d3.js sankey diagram - change particle density and shape

Tags: d3.js, sankey-diagram

I am developing a sankey diagram using D3 and code found [here](https://bl.ocks.org/emeeks/9673c96a682fe3948379), but how can I make the particles as dense as [this](https://www.nytimes.com/interactive/2018/03/27/upshot/make-your-own-mobility-animation.html) and square-shaped? Unfortunately I've not been able to figure this out yet.

I believe this code snippet might be relevant:

```
  var linkExtent = d3.extent(energy.links, function (d) {return d.value});
  var frequencyScale = d3.scale.linear().domain(linkExtent).range([0.05,1]);
  var particleSize = d3.scale.linear().domain(linkExtent).range([1,5]);


  energy.links.forEach(function (link) {
    link.freq = frequencyScale(link.value);
    link.particleSize = 2.5;
    link.particleColor = d3.scale.linear().domain([0,1])
    .range([link.source.color, link.target.color]);
  })
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

> how can I make the particles as dense as this

you should decrease timer's delay and add more particles at each tick.

> and square-shaped

You should use context.fillRect() instead of context.arc() on canvas.

Comment: I replaced `context.arc(currentPos.x,currentPos.y + particles[x].offset,particles[x].link.particleSize,0,2*Math.PI);` with `context.fillRect(currentPos.x,currentPos.y + particles[x].offset,5,5);` Which worked, thank you. I've also decreased the delay via `var t = d3.timer(tick, 1000);`, but how do I increase the particles produced at each tick? – Sidders

Comment: Can you post live example?

Comment: You should push multiple circles or rects at each tick.

Comment: I've tried changing `freqCounter`, `frequencyScale`, `link.freq` and experimenting with the `if (Math.random() < d.freq)` statement but I'm not seeing a dense stream of particles (e.g. especially on the 'Nuclear' path). Do you know what I'm doing wrong? Unfortunately I don't know exactly how to push more particles at each tick.

Thank you for your help so far.